# Is there a way of accessing billing contact details in the servicem8 API / zapier integration

Tags: webhooks

I've read this question / answer
[Feeding contact details into servicem8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28870052/feeding-contact-details-into-servicem8)

but it seems to offer workarounds rather than showing how to access billing contact details.

Job contact is useful for individual customers, but billing contact details are required when trying to work with landlords as an example.

For example, when adding new clients to hubspot CRM from servicem8, I don't want to add job contact details because that's the tenant - I want to add billing contact details - the landlord.

Answer (score 1):

Billing contact fields aren't part of the ServiceM8 Zapier trigger for "New Client", so they can't be used in zaps for that trigger.

Billing contact details are part of the ServiceM8 API though, you can access them via the [CompanyContacts endpoint](http://developer.servicem8.com/docs/rest-api/reference/companycontact-3/).

You will need to apply a filter to get only the CompanyContacts for the Company (i.e. client) you are interested in:

```
curl -u email:password "https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/CompanyContact.json?%24filter=company_uuid%20eq%2000000000-0000-4000-a000-000000000000"
```